# Ember build failed because of broccoliBuilderError

Tags: javascript, npm, ember.js, build, broccolijs

I am on an ember project and I am trying to upgrade ember version from 2.8 to 3.5.0. But since I changed the version and also some several dependencies version I get this error :

[Error stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqNYz.png)

I've tried to fix this with ember-cli-build file but the error persisted.

```
const EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
    const isPublicEnv = EmberApp.env() === 'public';

    const app = new EmberApp(defaults, {

        'sassOptions': {
            includePaths: [
                'bower_components/materialize/sass',
            ],
        },
        'outputPaths': {
            app: {
                css: {
                    design1: '/assets/design1.css',
                    design2: '/assets/design2.css'
                },
            },
        },
        'ember-cli-babel': {
            includePolyfill: true,
        },
        'minifyJS': {
            enabled: isPublicEnv,
        },
        'minifyCSS': {
            enabled: isPublicEnv,
        },
        'fingerprint': {
            enabled: isPublicEnv,
        },
        'tests': !isPublicEnv,
        'hinting': !isPublicEnv,
        'sourcemaps': {
            enabled: !isPublicEnv,
        },
    });

    app.import('vendor/lib1.js');
    app.import('vendor/lib2.js');

    return app.toTree();
};
```

Any suggestion to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that's failing from your stack trace from [ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile/blob/master/index.js):

```
templateCompilerPath() {
    let config = this.projectConfig();
    let templateCompilerPath = config['ember-cli-htmlbars'] && config['ember-cli-htmlbars'].templateCompilerPath;

    let ember = this.project.findAddonByName('ember-source');
    if (ember) {
      return ember.absolutePaths.templateCompiler;
    }

    return path.resolve(this.project.root, templateCompilerPath);
}
```

This line `let ember = this.project.findAddonByName('ember-source');` must be the culprit. Although Ember switched from bower to npm around `2.11` iirc, the only way you could be getting Ember > `3.0` is via npm since the last bower pushed version was the end of `2.x`.

I suspect you are on an old version of `ember-cli` that needs to also be updated since `ember` is not found. Which version of `ember-cli` are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Before upgrading it was ember-cli 2.8 but now I've changed it to ember-cli 3.5.0

Comment: and this is failing with `3.5.0`? did you use the ember cli upgrade tool?

Comment: No, in fact what I did is that I removed all installed modules in node_modules of project, I did a research to know the depdencies that I need to change after changing ember-cli to 3.5.0 and I updated the version in package.json. Then I lunched npm install && bower install

Comment: Follow the instructions here: `https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases` Run ember-cli-update -- This will update your app or addon to the latest ember-cli release. You will probably encounter merge conflicts that you should resolve in your normal git workflow. This is the most important step.

Comment: Well, I will try ember-cli-update and I will inform you the result Thank you